# Question about the energy-momentum tensor and tetrad formalism

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Given a metric tensor, you have an Einstein tensor associated with it. If your Einstein tensor is diagonal, you can "match it" with a diagonal energy-momentum tensor. More over, if your metric is diagonal, the energy-momentum tensor will be too.

But this question relies on the physics of the act, when one chooses to write all quantities as a tetrad frame, (seriously, why is that?). I'll elaborate more.

Suppose you have the Einstein Field Equations (EFE) like this:

$$\begin{pmatrix}G_{00}& 0 & 0 & 0\\0 &G_{11} &0 &0\\ 0&0 & G_{22}&0\\ 0& 0& 0&G_{33} \end{pmatrix} = 8\pi\begin{pmatrix}T_{00}& 0 & 0 & 0\\0 &T_{11} &0 &0\\ 0&0 & T_{22}&0\\ 0& 0& 0&T_{33} \end{pmatrix}.  \tag{1}$$

But now, consider the EFE in some tetrad frame

$$\begin{pmatrix}G_{\hat{0}\hat{0}}& 0 & 0 & 0\\0 &G_{\hat{1}\hat{1}} &0 &0\\ 0&0 & G_{\hat{2}\hat{2}}&0\\ 0& 0& 0&G_{\hat{3}\hat{3}} \end{pmatrix} = 8\pi\begin{pmatrix}T_{\hat{0}\hat{0}}& 0 & 0 & 0\\0 &T_{\hat{1}\hat{1}} &0 &0\\ 0&0 & T_{\hat{2}\hat{2}}&0\\ 0& 0& 0&T_{\hat{3}\hat{3}} \end{pmatrix}.  \tag{2}$$

Many papers shows tensor quantities in tetrad basis, because in these orthonormal frames, things tend to simplify. But, in Eric Poisson's book "Relativist Toolkit", he mentioned that every energy-momentum tensor can be decomposed like:

$$T = T_{\hat{\mu}\hat{\nu}} \hat{e}^{\mu}\otimes\hat{e}^{\nu} = \rho \hat{e}^{0}\otimes\hat{e}^{0} + p_{1}\hat{e}^{1}\otimes\hat{e}^{1}+p_{2}\hat{e}^{2}\otimes\hat{e}^{2}+p_{3}\hat{e}^{3}\otimes\hat{e}^{3}.\tag{3}$$

And, it is commonly said that you are allowed to say that the $T_{00}$, in equation $(1)$, is indeed the energy density just when you write the whole EFE in a tetrad frame, i.e., $\rho = T_{\hat{0}\hat{0}}$ (though I don't understand why!). Furthermore, it is common to see $\rho = T_{00}$, but it seems to work just when the metric is simple and the Einstein tensor is diagonal; the whole thing with tetrads can be suppressed. Like in Schwarschild or Morris-Thorne cases.

> Considering the tetrad basis formalism, equation $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$, why do the the energy-momentum components gain physical meaning JUST when you put the whole thing (project it) in a tetrad frame?